# Code is not running properly when I run with If else conditions, It gives me only if condition or else condition, Main code is not executing

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the code I want to run. The problem is When I want to run the code with the condition "Swipe Loading" It gives me only circular progress indicator on the screen. When I comment this condition and run with only "Swipe Loaded" Condition, It show the else condition that is "Something went wrong". I don't know why internal code is not executing that is the main code for the page. If there is any error or important to add something please let me know.

@override

Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(

```
appBar: const CustomAppBar(
  title: 'Home',
),
body: BlocBuilder<SwipeBloc, SwipeState>(
  builder: (context, state) { 
    //      if (state is SwipeLoading) {
    //        Text("swipeloading");
    //   return Center(
    //     // child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    //   );
    // } else if (state is SwipeLoaded) {
       if (state is SwipeLoaded) {
    //   Text("SwipeLoaded");
      var userCount = state.users.length;
      return Column(
        children: [
          InkWell(
            onDoubleTap: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/users',
                arguments: state.users[0]);
            },
            child: Draggable<User>(
            data: state.users[0],
              child: UserCard(user: state.users[0]),
              feedback: UserCard(user: state.users[0]),
              childWhenDragging: (userCount > 1) ?
                UserCard(user: state.users[1]): Container(),
              onDragEnd: (drag) {
                if (drag.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx < 0) {
                  context.read<SwipeBloc>()
                    .add(SwipeLeft(user: state.users[0]));
                  // ignore: avoid_print
                  print('Swiped left');
                } else {
                  context.read<SwipeBloc>()
                    .add(SwipeRight(user: state.users[0]));
                  // ignore: avoid_print
                  print('Swiped right');
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 8.0,
              horizontal: 60,
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    context.read<SwipeBloc>()
                  .add(SwipeLeft(user: state.users[0]));
                // ignore: avoid_print
                print('Swiped left');
                  },
                  child: ChoiceButton(
                    width: 60,
                    height: 60,
                    size: 25,
                    hasGradient: false,
                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                    icon: Icons.clear_rounded,
                  ),
                ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    context.read<SwipeBloc>()
                  .add(SwipeRight(user: state.users[0]));
                // ignore: avoid_print
                print('Swiped right');
                  },
                  child: const ChoiceButton(
                    width: 80,
                    height: 80,
                    size: 30,
                    hasGradient: true,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    icon: Icons.coffee,
                  ),
                ),
                ChoiceButton(
                  width: 60,
                  height: 60,
                  size: 25,
                  hasGradient: false,
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  icon: Icons.watch_later,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);



}
   if (state is SwipeError) {
     return Center(
     child: Text('There are\'t any more users.',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3),
       );
     }
     else {
       return const Text('Something went wrong.');
     }
    },
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you  change all conditions  such as `if(state is SwipeLoaded)` to `if(state == SwipeLoaded)`. Are you using Stateless or Stateful widget?

Comment: Yes I will try, I am using Stateless Widget

Comment: I tried your condition but it gives me error on "users", It doesn't take the value of  "users".